# RandR with internal intel iGPU and old Trident card

Tags: linux, xorg, xrandr, multi-monitor

I have a problem with a 2 graphics card configuration. I have an 
internal intel (iGPU i7 4xxx) and a very old Trident TGUI 9xxx PCI card. If I 
use the card as primary kde starts great, but i need configure in Multi-Monitor 
mode. I can't use Xinerama because then the XOrg server don't start. With the 
current configuration i have the main display OK and the second display 
(connected to the Trident) in black with the cursor as X (i can move the 
cursor to that display).
If I enable Xinerama then the XOrg restart indefinitely in a loop, seems the incompatibility of Xinerama and XRandR.

So how enable this two monitors with two cards??

xrandr don't detect my second screen, this are the outuputs:

```
xrandr --listproviders

Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x45 cap: 0xb, Source Output, Sink Output, Sink Offload 
crtcs: 3 
outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:Intel


xrandr --q

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 
410mm x 230mm
   1366x768      59.79*+
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I'm using Debian testing with Xorg 1:7.7+19 amd64 this is my config:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/97-intel.conf

Section "Device"
    Identifier      "intel"
    Driver          "intel"

    BusID           "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Screen 0"
    Device          "intel"
    Monitor         "Monitor 0"
    DefaultDepth    16
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "Monitor 0"
    Option          "DPMS"
EndSection
```

---

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/98-trident.conf

Section "Device"
    Identifier      "tridentcard"
    Driver          "trident"

    Option          "NoAccel" "True"
    Option          "ShadowFB" "Enable"
    Option          "NoPciBurst" "Enable"
    Option          "FramebufferWC"

    Option          "NoDDC"
    Option          "UseTiming800"

    Option          "AccelMethod" "EXA"
    BusID           "PCI:5:0:0"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Screen 1"
    Device          "tridentcard"
    Monitor         "Monitor 1"
    DefaultDepth    16
    SubSection "Display"
         Depth    16
         Modes    "640x480_60"
         Virtual  800 600
    EndSubSection
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "Monitor 1"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 62.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 70.0
EndSection
```

---

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-layout.conf 

Section "ServerLayout"
  Identifier   "Main"
  Screen       0 "Screen 0"
  Screen       1 "Screen 1" RightOf "Screen 0"
  Option         "Xinerama" "0" 
EndSection
```

Comment: Does the Trident driver even support Xinerama and RandR? IIRC it was written long before those existed, and I doubt someone has had interest in updating it ...

Comment: I think that the trident driver doesn't support the XRandR, but then if I can disable XRandR in my Intel and set the Xinerama for both of them....